# Datetime index replaced after creating csv file from dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(data)
```

Output:

```
       code  trade_date   open   high    low  close       volume
0       2GO  2012-06-04  1.750  1.750  1.750  1.750       5000.0
1       2GO  2012-06-05  1.750  1.980  1.750  1.900       8000.0
2       2GO  2012-06-07  1.960  1.960  1.800  1.800       8000.0
3       2GO  2012-06-11  1.900  1.980  1.900  1.980      50000.0
4       2GO  2012-06-13  1.990  1.990  1.900  1.900      19000.0
```

I want to set the trade_date as index . . .

```
data.set_index('trade_date', inplace=True)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
           code   open   high    low  close       volume
trade_date
2012-06-04  2GO  1.750  1.750  1.750  1.750       5000.0
2012-06-05  2GO  1.750  1.980  1.750  1.900       8000.0
2012-06-07  2GO  1.960  1.960  1.800  1.800       8000.0
2012-06-11  2GO  1.900  1.980  1.900  1.980      50000.0
2012-06-13  2GO  1.990  1.990  1.900  1.900      19000.0
```

. . . then write it to a csv file.

```
data.to_csv('data_reidx.csv')
```

However when I read the csv file again, trade_date is back to being a column and was replaced by traditional indexing.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data_reidx.csv')
```

Output:

```
        trade_date code   open   high    low  close       volume
0       2012-06-04  2GO  1.750  1.750  1.750  1.750       5000.0
1       2012-06-05  2GO  1.750  1.980  1.750  1.900       8000.0
2       2012-06-07  2GO  1.960  1.960  1.800  1.800       8000.0
3       2012-06-11  2GO  1.900  1.980  1.900  1.980      50000.0
4       2012-06-13  2GO  1.990  1.990  1.900  1.900      19000.0
```

How do I preserve the datetime index when writing dataframe to csv?

Comment: Can you try ***data = pd.read_csv('data_reidx.csv', index_col='trade_date')***. let me know if it worked.

Comment: @itaybenhaim this worked. In ```data.to_csv('data_reidx.csv', index_label=False)```, the date index is preserved even when reading the csv normally, but the 'trade_date' column name is gone.
Both works just fine. The column name is not important in my case.

Comment: feel free to upvote :)

Comment: @itaybenhaim will do when I get to 15 rep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try telling pandas which column is the index when you load it:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data_reidx.csv', index_col='trade_date')
```

Here is a nice guide that explains it better than i can if you need more help: https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_dataframe_importing_csv/

Answer (score 2):

Try to get rid of the [index_label](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) -

```
data.to_csv('data_reidx.csv', index_label=False )
```

Next time you read, read it normally -

```
data = pd.read_csv('data_reidx.csv')
```

**Output**

```
           code  open  high   low  close   volume
2012-06-04  2GO  1.75  1.75  1.75   1.75   5000.0
2012-06-05  2GO  1.75  1.98  1.75   1.90   8000.0
2012-06-07  2GO  1.96  1.96  1.80   1.80   8000.0
2012-06-11  2GO  1.90  1.98  1.90   1.98  50000.0
2012-06-13  2GO  1.99  1.99  1.90   1.90  19000.0
```